# MVC ViewModel [Required] DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel where I have a field called Type be required:

```
    [Required]  
   public string Type{ get; set; }
```

I am using this viewmodel on different pages but in some cases, the Type is not required.
I am wondering how I can tell a page to not have Type be Required.

What I tried was to put a

```
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type)
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same view model for whatever reason have a look at using the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) library, foolproof aims to extend the Data Annotation validation provided in ASP.NET MVC. Initial efforts are focused on adding contingent validation.

The required attributes out of he box are:

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

The beauty of Foolproof is that it supports client side validation using unobstrusive techniques out of the box.

So in your case

```
[RequiredIfTrue("ShouldValidateType"]  
public string Type{ get; set; } 

public bool ShouldValidateType {get; set;}
```

The property type would only validate if ShouldValidateType is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `RequiredAttribute`

Either write / get a custom conditional attribute, like `RequiredIfAttribute` (an example  [here](https://gist.github.com/1547191))

Or use [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead of DataAnnotations.

Or use different ViewModels.